# Prepending a Div Before a Div Having Left value Zero

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have tried to prepend a Div before a Div Having left value Zero.
 But as a result the prepended Div Replaces the Olden Div's Position 
i.e] The Prepended Div Now has the left value '0' 

Here is the code i had used For prepending,

```
   $("#xx").prepend("<div> Hello </div>");
```

**EDIT**

[image]

Is there any possibility to prepend a div Before a div with negative left values?

Comment: `div`s are block elements by default, so I assume you have a css rule to convert them to `inline`/`inline-block`? It'd be nice if you could make a http://jsfiddle.net to demonstrate the issue.

Comment: You want to prepend a div (`.new`) before a div (`.old`) that has a negative left value (`.old` has a `left` value < 0), or you want the prepended div to have the negative `left` value?

Comment: @DavidThomas Both the things are needed for me. Because Whenever user is clicking on a specific button i need to prepend a div before the current div and animate from the old to new. (move divs from left to right)

Answer (score 0):

```
 $("#xx").prepend("<div class='prediv'> Hello </div>");
```

like that?

```
.prediv{
   position: absolute;
   left:  -100px; 
 }
```

I don't think this is exactly what it will look like , but you get the idea , just put the class in the prepend string and apply the necessary rules to where you want the div to go, by default it will not go out side of the parent with a negative left value

Answer (score 0):

you can do the following

```
var mydiv  = $('<div>');//now you can do everything like :
mydiv.css('left','-100px')/*.attr('sth','sth')*/;//prepare it as you like
$("#xx").prepend(mydiv); // now prepend will add it
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try this out and post back the result.